# Calculating Time Difference between two rows while resetting for a group - Hot, and Thank you Community

Tags: sql, row, between, intersect, time-difference

In my case, I have different Partners (ENCOUNTER_ID).  Each one can have one or multiple assessments.
I need to calculate the time difference between each each one of their assessments.  With time resetting for each partner.  Time Difference field is the field I would like created.

In the case below Joe had two assessments, the first marked w 0 since it is the first in the instance, the second one being 81 minutes from the first one.

Mike Only had one assessment, so no calculation is needed.

Olivia had 5 assessments, the first marked as 0 since it is the first, and then each one has time difference from prior assessment.

I am attaching the sample data with the ?? field being the one I need assistance with.  I am also attaching my current qry that I am using. I am using this as part of an intersect so I am attaching the code as well.

Thank you all so much, I know this is probably a piece of cake for many of you.

I tried using CTE's with row number and Over partitions, I tried using Lag window functions, and could not get the right results.

this is what I do have that is working but not giving me the right result for the time difference field.

```
Select distinct
   e.ENCOUNTER_ID as ENCNTR_ID
  ,d.FORM_DT_TM Assessment_DtTm
  ,count(DISTINCT e.ENCOUNTER_ID) as Assessment_Count
  ,case when e.ENCOUNTER_ID Is NOT NULL then datediff(second,d.FORM_DT_TM,lag(d.FORM_DT_TM) over(order     
    by d.FORM_DT_TM)) else null end

from KDHCD_P607.PERSON P
 join KDHCD_EDW_MILL_CDS.MD_F_ENCOUNTER E on P.person_id=E.person_id --and e.active_ind=1
 join KDHCD_P607.DCP_FormS_Activity D on P.person_id=D.person_ID and e.ENCOUNTER_ID=d.encntr_id and    
                                                          d.DCP_FORMS_REF_ID  IN  ( 2384507453  )
 join KDHCD_P607.DCP_FORMS_ACTIVITY_COMP DC on D.DCP_FORMS_ACTIVITY_ID=DC.DCP_FORMS_ACTIVITY_ID and 
                                           D.active_ind=1 AND DC.PARENT_ENTITY_NAME = 'CLINICAL_EVENT'
 join kdhcd_p607.clinical_event cs on cs.PARENT_EVENT_ID=dc.PARENT_ENTITY_ID and  Cs.VIEW_LEVEL=0 
 join  kdhcd_p607.clinical_event cd on cs.EVENT_ID=Cd.PARENT_EVENT_ID and Cd.VIEW_LEVEL=1 and 
                              cd.event_Cd in (703614)  --Field that differs from both queries

where p.ACTIVE_IND=1 
  and e.REGISTRATION_DT_TM > '11/1/2023'
group by 
  e.ENCOUNTER_ID 
 ,d.FORM_DT_TM
```

Comment: Sample data is worth a thousand words. It's much easier to follow if you present your data (input and expected) as a markdown formatted table https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302471/how-to-put-tables-in-stack-overflow

Comment: Also, please tag your DBMS (Sql server, Oracle, MySQL, etc...)

Comment: Column REGISTRATION_DT_TM data type?

Comment: Please make a [mre] to avoid ambiguity and give us something concrete to work with. [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952)

Comment: Please also describe how the current result of your query differs from what you want. It looks more or less reasonable. Grouping by ENCOUNTER_ID and FORM_DT_TM but having your derived column not be an aggregate function could cause some strange behavior.

Comment: @Error_2646 All the scalar values in the select block are in the group by. Also having distinct is odd though. And `count(distinct x) group by x` can only ever yield 0 or 1, which is odd. I think without a [mre] the whole question is too ambiguous.

Comment: I think you are close. If you just need to "reset" for each patient or encounter, you need to add a `partition by` to your `LAG() OVER(...)` qualifier. Try changing `over(order by d.FORM_DT_TM)` to something like `over(partition by P.person_id order by d.FORM_DT_TM)` or `over(partition by e.ENCOUNTER_ID order by d.FORM_DT_TM)`.  Adding an `ISNULL(..., 0)` around your `DATEDIFF(...)` will map the first difference to zero, when there is no prior assessment.

Comment: As a side note, I believe `count(DISTINCT e.ENCOUNTER_ID) as Assessment_Count` will never return any value other than 1 when paired with `group by e.ENCOUNTER_ID, ...`,

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  thank you all either way.

```
**,case when e.ENCOUNTER_ID is not null 
        then (datediff(MINUTE,d.FORM_DT_TM,lag(d.FORM_DT_TM) over(Partition by 
 e.ENCOUNTER_ID order by d.FORM_DT_TM)))* -1 
        else -1 end**
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).